# TextVariable not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the Text out of an Entry widget in Tkinter. It works with Entry1.get(), but it does not work using textvariable

What am I doing wrong ?

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
v = StringVar()

def Entered(p1):
    print 'Got: ', Entry1.get()
    print 'Got: ', v.get()

Entry1 = Entry(master, text = '', width = 25, textvariable = v)
Entry1.pack()
Entry1.bind('<Return>', Entered)
```

Comment: What's not working? It works for me.

Comment: It's because you are using text in there. If you remove it, it works fine. As for _why_, that I don't know and searching for.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `text`.

If you give the `text` argument, it seems that the `textvariable.get()` will return nothing. I don't know if its a bug or not.

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
v = StringVar()

def Entered(p1):
    print 'Got: ', Entry1.get()
    print 'Got: ', v.get()

Entry1 = Entry(master, width = 25, textvariable = v) # No text now
Entry1.pack()
Entry1.bind('<Return>', Entered)
master.mainloop()
```

If you enter `asd` it returns:

```
Got:  asd
Got:  asd
```

The interesting part that if you change the entry to:

```
Entry1 = Entry(master, text = 'sajt', width = 25, textvariable = v)
```

It will still return nothing with `v.get()` not `sajt` as i would expect.

Comment: The entry widget has no option `text`. Tkinter treats it a shorthand for `textvariable`. Using it is no different than using `textvariable` twice, and tkinter uses the first one.

Comment: Yeah thats what i thought as well, but if you check the main page of tkinter entry there is an example with both text and textvariable.

Comment: Which "main page" are you talking about?  If there's a page that uses both, it's wrong.

Comment: Here http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm you can find a line:  entry = Entry(parent, text=caption, textvariable=content). Yeah the "main" is not a good word.

Comment: that page is incorrect. I'll try to contact the author.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm sorry for bothering but I don't understand what do you mean by 'uses the first one'? alpabetically? because behaviour doesn't change if `(... ,textvariable=v, text='', ...)`. And my source code reading skills failed me really bad, so asking seems like my last option.

Comment: Ok, well maybe "first one" was inaccurate. Maybe it uses the shortest one? Regardless, the fact is, `text` is not a supported attribute of an `Entry` widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley Do you have a reference for `text` being an alias for `textvariable`? I cannot find it in `Tkinter` doc (incomplete as it is) or even Tk man. And when I tested OP's code using Python 2.7.3, it actually worked.

Comment: @gill: _"Command-line switches may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is unambiguous. "_ from https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/options.htm. Definitive list of options for the entry widget is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks. I missed that meta rule. Still a mystery why OP's code works for me though.