# Button Label - text vs textvariable

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, ttk

TTK Button: text vs textvariable
I am trying to set the button label text to "Hi" as a default and, on clicking it, change its text to "Hello"

I have tried multiple methods to get the text to change.

If I set the `text` = "Hi" it's fine, but whenever I add in the `textvariable`, it breaks and displays no text label on the button, itself.

Is there something wrong with adding both the 
`text` and `textvariable` arguments when constructing the button in tkinter, as below?

From *Python GUI Programming with Tkinter* by **Alan D. Moore**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tvar = tk.StringVar()
def swaptext():
    if tvar.get() == 'Hi':
        tvar.set('There')
    else:
        tvar.set('Hi')

# my_button = ttk.Button(parent, text='Hi', textvariable=tvar, command=swaptext) # BUTTON LABEL IS BLANK
my_button = ttk.Button(parent, text='Hi', command=swaptext) # WORKS, BUT NO TEXTVARIABLE TO CALL TO SWAP TEXT
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I expect the button to show, immediately, with "Hi" given the default `text` value is set to "Hi", but it actually starts out BLANK. Though it starts blank, when I click the button, it toggles from:

- BLANK --> Hi
- Hi --> Hello
- Hello --> Hi (etc. etc.)

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong as to why my default button `text` value and the `textvariable`?

The closest I found to an answer was here: [TextVariable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475373/textvariable-not-working), but this was in regards to Entry constructors, which don't appear to take `text` as an argument.

If I missed an answer to this, I apologize, but I'm not seeing one listed anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set a default value for your `StringVar`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tvar = tk.StringVar(value="Hi")

def swaptext():
    if tvar.get() == 'Hi':
        tvar.set('There')
    else:
        tvar.set('Hi')

my_button = ttk.Button(root, textvariable=tvar, command=swaptext)
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OMG! Such an easy fix. This was new to me and I should have looked up the documentation for `StringVar()`

I sincerely appreciate the help, and wish this was spelled out in the book! Thank you thank you thank you!